# Django TemplateDoesNotExist on Google App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I keep getting `TemplateDoesNotExist` and I can't figure out how to debug it. I've added the folder in which the template sits into the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` tuple and when I call `get_template` from within my `.py` file, the template loads fine, however when I call it from within a template fine using the `extends` tag, it raises `TemplateDoesNotExist`.

The template file isn't under a `static_files` path in the `app.yaml`.

What confuses me is why it loads fine with `get_template` but not with `extend`.

Is there a way I can find out the path in which Django is looking?

Comment: Is your `extends` tag use quotes for template name?

Comment: That's my extend tag: `{% extends "base.html" %}`

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

```
from django.conf import settings
print settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS
```

to see the used template dir path.

Comment: This returns the correct paths. Is there a way to find out the path which is causing the `TemplateDoesNotExist` in question?

Comment: Not sure, but the answer to this question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038459/django-template-path . It shows you how to setup the template_dirs setting correctly. You might have an issue there.

Comment: If this does not help, you could also try (for debugging purposes) the django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader, for which the docs can be found here:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#loader-types - it loads the templates from a template folder below your app folder. It is enabled by default, but if not just add this string 'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader' to your TEMPLATE_LOADERS setting.