# Django Admin Template Missing after S3 Setup

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm running a Django locally using Heroku, with static + media files hosted on S3. However, my admin templates have gone missing. I've followed this config - [Django template Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038459/django-template-path) - so my `TEMPLATE_DIRS` file is as follows:

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (PROJECT_PATH + '/templates/')

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)
```

I've noticed that my browser is still looking for the admin CSS files on S3 but, as this is my first time setting up and deploying, I'm a bit lost as to how to configure this properly.

Comment: did u collect static file and put them in the *right* folder of s3? 
btw, if you solve this you probably also solve: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972696/jquery-script-in-django-app-not-working-after-s3-setup

Comment: @EsseTi I think so, S3 is collecting other static files properly. Is there a specific admin css file that needs to be in there?

Comment: `collectstatic` collects all the static files. so there should be no problem. if django-admin in the installed apps? does S3 grant access to the folder (so if you put manually the url, can you see the files?)