# In Django, is it possible to define a dynamically calculated setting based in another?

Tags: python, django, settings

(Maybe this question is more about Python but Django is the context, so here it goes)

Suppose you need a setting `FOO` whose value depends on the value of setting `BAR` (simplest case is make `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND` equal to `BROKER_URL`).

If you have only one settings file, that's simple to achieve:

```
BAR = some_value
FOO = some_function(BAR)
```

However, it's quite popular to have many settings files, one for each environment (e.g. production, development, test, stage, etc), as proposed in the [project layout](https://github.com/twoscoops/django-twoscoops-project) from the book, "Two Scoops of Django: Best Practices for Django 1.5".

In that case there is a `settings.base` module, which is imported with all its contents by `settings.dev`, `settings.prod`, etc, which add their own specific values or override those defined in `settings.base`.

The problem happens when I want to override `BAR` in some of those modules, but I have to remember to recalculate `FOO` every time after that override. That's error prone and not DRY.

A lambda function won't work because that setting would be a callable, not the resulting value. Built-in function/decorator [`property`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) would be ideal but it can only be used within classes (new-style). I don't know anything else like that.

Ideas?

Comment: Hmm.  It's a bit untidy, but maybe split out your dependent settings into a different file and import that after setting BAR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly hackish:

```
class DynamicWrapper(object):
    _initialized = False

    def __init__(self, wrapped_name)
        self._wrapped = wrapped_name

    def __get__(self):
        if not self._initialized:
            self._initialized = True
            return self
        if not hasattr(self, '_computed_val'):
            from django.conf import settings
            val = getattr(settings, self._wrapped)
            self._computed_val = some_func(val)
        return self._computed_val

BAR = 'some_value'
FOO = DynamicWrapper('BAR')
```

The idea is as follows:

- Django's settings object uses `getattr(settings_module, setting)` once when the settings object is initialized (note that when you do `from django.conf import settings` you actually import an object, not a module). The result is set as an attribute on the settings object. `__get__` is called, returning `self`, thus `settings.FOO` is the `DynamicWrapper` instance.
- When `settings.FOO` is accessed, this will call `__get__` a second time on the `DynamicWrapper` object, this is when you want it to return the actual value. The value is computed according to `some_func` and the value is returned instead of the `DynamicWrapper` object.
- Any subsequent attempt to get the value of `settings.FOO` will also call the `__get__` method, but this time the computed value is cached as `self._computed_val` and immediately returned.

This doesn't handle the (edge) cases when there are multiple `Settings` objects, when `FOO` is accessed in another way than through `django.conf.settings` or when `BAR` is not defined.

Comment: Good idea although it certainly is hackish way to achieve what I wanted. It never crossed my mind to approach the problem this way. Congrats

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is, the settings file is just a python script as well.

Most people do it already to build the Template Path setting.

[Django template Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038459/django-template-path)

Now let's imagine this:

```
ref = {
    'dev':  'FOO',
    'qa':   'BAR'
    'prod': 'BAZ'
}

ENV = 'PROD'  # Can also be DEV or QA

DYNAMIC_SETTING = ref.get(ENV.lower(), None)  # => 'BAZ'
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I needed. What you post as `DYNAMIC_SETTING` isn't so: if I change `ENV` after your snippet, and then access `DYNAMIC_SETTING` again, its value will not change. Why? Because that line (`DYNAMIC_SETTING = ref ...`) was already executed and won't again.