# What is the purpose of adding to INSTALLED_APPS in Django?

Tags: python, django

Most documentation simply tells you to add the name of each of your apps to the INSTALLED_APPS array in your Django project's settings. What is the benefit/purpose of this? What different functionality will I get if I create 2 apps, but only include the name of one in my INSTALLED_APPS array?

Comment: In addition to what Robert Townley mentioned, I'd like to add that adding your app to INSTALLED_APPS also helps by making your app's templates discoverable. The default DjangoTemplates backend looks for the 'templates' folder only within the apps included in INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: @AmosP You can and should just use `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')` as your templates folder so that is not relevant to `INSTALLED_APPS` (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3038459/8285811)). Also, this should be a comment on the relevant answer.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Django uses `INSTALLED_APPS` as a list of all of the places to look for models, management commands, tests, and other utilities.

If you made two apps (say `myapp` and `myuninstalledapp`), but only one was listed in `INSTALLED_APPS`, you'd notice the following behavior:

1. The models contained in `myuninstalledapp/models.py` would never trigger migration changes (or generate initial migrations). You wouldn't be able to interact with them on the database level either because their tables will have never been created.
2. Static files listed within `myapp/static/` would be discovered as part of collectstatic or the test server's staticfiles serving, but `myuninstalledapp/static` files wouldn't be.
3. Tests within `myapp/tests.py` would run but `myuninstalledapp/tests.py` wouldn't.
4. Management commands listed in `myuninstalledapp/management/commands/` wouldn't be discovered.

So really, you're welcome to have folders within your Django project that aren't installed apps (you can even create them with `python manage.py startapp`) but just know that certain auto-discovery Django utilities won't work for that application.

Comment: Additional to point 1: reverse relationships wouldn't be created for models which are pointed to by ForeignKeys from myuninstalledapp.